LIGHTBOX ERROR - Invalid range in character class at offset 4
My forms page is unable to upload candidate information. An error appears when clicking send (Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method) and when I contacted the website hosting they informed me that it was an error in LIGHTBOX.
Image follows... How to fix it? I'm new to this.
lightbox error
I didn't tried. I do not know how to fix, i'm a neewbie

A regular expression passed to preg_match contained a faulty characters class, that's all we can tell from the error message. That could either be an error directly in the code of the plugin you are using there; or it could be due to an unexpected value passed in from the outside (something to do with your lightbox configuration/setup.) First step to get more information, would be to check what the code in that place actually looks like, and what values the parameters have when it throws that error.
